# UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for byte[] dji.midware.natives.SDKRelativeJNI.native_getXXX (...)

Tags: android, dji-sdk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

**Description:**
After updating android sdk to version 28 and DJI sdk from version 4.6 to 4.9 there is a problem with app working on any emulator. During DJI sdk registering app crashes.

- **DJI sdk:** 4.9
- **Android sdk (compileSdkVersion):** 28
- **Android system version:** every
- **Android device:** emulator

**Crash stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for byte[] dji.midware.natives.SDKRelativeJNI.native_getXXXX(java.lang.String) (tried Java_dji_midware_natives_SDKRelativeJNI_native_1getXXXX and Java_dji_midware_natives_SDKRelativeJNI_native_1getXXXX__Ljava_lang_String_2)
at dji.midware.natives.SDKRelativeJNI.native_getXXXX(Native Method)
at com.dji.h.a.a.c.b(Unknown Source)
at dji.midware.e.b(Unknown Source)
at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.(Unknown Source)
at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at PACKAGE_NAME.dji.DJIProvider$registerTask$1.run(DJIProvider.kt:39)
at PACKAGE_NAME.dji.DJIProvider.startSDKRegistration(DJIProvider.kt:127)
at PACKAGE_NAME.MainActivity$registerDJISDK$1.onExecutorReady(MainActivity.kt:595)
at PACKAGE_NAME..helpers.ui.SimpleDelayedExecutor$executeDelayed$1.run(DelayedExecutor.kt:20)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

DJI needs to get their act togethor on this issue:

1) In Android Studio, when you create a new Virtual Device, when you get to Select a system image go to the Other images tab. From there select any of the 'arm' images and use that. The emulator will be extremely slow with this option, and might not run at all if your computer is old or slow.

2) Connect a real Android device to your computer with debugging mode enabled and run the demo on that.

3) In your build.gradle file, set compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 22 which is the latest version in which DJI's provided libffmpeg.so file will load. This is the worst option though, as Google doesn't allow anybody to publish apps with SDK versions this    low anymore. The version must be 26 or above now:    https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk

4) Rollback to 4.6 :P